# What does it mean when Postgres query state is null

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

What does it mean when a query state is `null`?

```
my_database_name> SELECT pid, datname, usename, application_name, query_start, state, state_change FROM pg_stat_activity;
+-------+------------------+------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+
| pid   | datname          | usename          | application_name         | query_start                   | state   | state_change                  |
|-------+------------------+------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------|
| 19093 | my_database_name | my_user_nam      | pgcli                    | 2020-02-07 12:58:54.665447+00 | active  | 2020-02-07 12:58:54.665449+00 |
| 13777 | my_database_name | some_other_user  | DBeaver 6.3.2 - Main     | <null>                        | <null>  | <null>                        |
| 13776 | my_database_name | some_other_user  | DBeaver 6.3.2 - Metadata | <null>                        | <null>  | <null>                        |
| 2036  | <null>           | <null>           |                          | <null>                        | <null>  | <null>                        |
+-------+------------------+------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the session with `pid` 2036 belongs to a different user, and you don't have the privileges to see that data.

Consider that the queries run in that session might contain data that you have no right to see.

You must either be a superuser or (in recent versions) be a member of the `pg_read_all_stats` role to see these data.